# Is there an efficient way to make an interactive map?

Tags: map-making

I'm looking for a way to map a world as was done in the Forgotten Realms [Interactive Atlas](https://secure.profantasy.com/fratlas/fratlashome.htm). I want the ability to be able to zoom into areas while maintaining scale, and to get down to battle maps.

The key feature would allow you to have an entire world mapped, and then be able to zoom in and scroll on the regions you're in. Details fade as you zoom out, taxing your RAM less. Another example of a map system would be:

http://oblivionmap.net/Cyrodiil.html

Comment: Could you give us some more details about exactly what your looking for (perhaps summarize the cool features of the interactive atlas that you'd like to see in a custom piece of software).

Comment: Essentially, it's Google Maps for a world of your creation, if I get the gist right.

Comment: A similar idea has been discussed for Worldbuilding.SE and even developed on a bit: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/558/ideas-for-a-worldbuilders-mapping-site

Answer (score 5):

For my d&d campaign, I use [mashupforge.com](http://mashupforge.com), which allows you to build an interactive map like the one you gave as an example.
As a proof of concept, you can refer to a map of mine, that is currently under construction: [Faerun](http://mashupforge.com/map/feerune/)

Comment: Love this. Will give it a try for our campaign.

Comment: It looks like Mashupforge was moved to http://www.encounterroleplay.com/mashupforge-custom-interactive-maps/

Comment: The website is now offline and seems to have not been relocated ...

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with [Maptools](http://www.rptools.net/?page=maptool), you can zoom in and out indefinitely, allowing you to create a map as big as you want. You would just need to zoom out a lot, create basic shapes for continents, landscapes, etc. Then zoom in to create the cities and whatnot, and zoom even more (to "ground level") to set the details, such as houses, trees, etc.

It would essentially be a gargantuan combat map, so big it covers the entire world.